# How to change the schema name using liquibase

Tags: h2, liquibase

I am using embedded database H2 which has default schema PUBLIC.
I want to have a schema XYZ as opposed to the default H2 schema. How can I change it using liquibase. I tried to create the very first changeset to create schema XYZ and added schemaName attribute to all the DDL statements henceforth to use the schemaName. But databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock are created in PUBLIC schema. How can specify the schema for those tables as well ?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST and specify 'defaultSchema' attribute to the 'schemaName' in the liquibase bean.